# Make chimp execution fail if running 0 tests

Tags: meteor, continuous-integration, automated-tests, chimp.js

Long story short, I have a meteor app passing in a continuous-integration pipeline which runs every tests before deploying. My tests run with chimp and I was installing chimp globally on my CI environment in each build with the latest version before running the tests.

recently, chimp made a somewhat major update which resulted in my chimp execution running 1..0 tests. After finding out it was because of the version of chimp, I made the change to the installation of chimp to be local and locked at a certain version.

The problem is that my pipeline was **passing** because hey, 0 tests passing is still 0 tests failing..!

I'm trying to make chimp fail if it runs no tests at all. How would be a good way to do it?

I tried greping the output and matching it to '1..0' resulting in a exit /b 1 status with no luck. The best solution would involve only the chimp command.

Thanks to anyone that could give me some hint on that.

Answer (score 0):

## Use the after test hook

You can put your code which runs after all tests in the `after` test hook (example below). I"m not sure on how to check check the number of tests run, but I think you can find out the same way the test reporter finds it. So, I'd suggest going through the source of one of the popular/simpler reporters like `dot`/`spec` and figuring it out from there.

```
describe('test', function() {
  after(function() { console.log('after'); });
  afterEach(function() { console.log('afterEach'); });

  it('fails sync', function(done) {
    after(function() { console.log('inner after 1'); });
    throw new Error('failed');
  });

  it('fails async', function(done) {
    after(function() { console.log('inner after 2'); });
    process.nextTick(function() {
      throw new Error('failed');
    });
  });
});
```

which produces the following output with mocha 1.1.12:

```
  ․afterEach
․afterEach
after
inner after 1
inner after 2


  0 passing (5 ms)
  2 failing

1) test fails sync:
 Error: failed
  at Context.<anonymous> (/private/tmp/so/test/main.js:7:11)
  at Test.Runnable.run (/private/tmp/so/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:194:15)
  at Runner.runTest (/private/tmp/so/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:355:10)
  at /private/tmp/so/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:401:12
  at next (/private/tmp/so/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:281:14)
  at /private/tmp/so/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:290:7
  at next (/private/tmp/so/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:234:23)
  at Object._onImmediate (/private/tmp/so/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:258:5)
  at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)

2) test fails async:
 Error: failed
  at /private/tmp/so/test/main.js:13:12
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

> credits for example code from SO user Miroslav Bajtoš